# Snowflake change data type of column in table, varchar -> Date

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do I change a varchar data type to a DATE for the column datatype in a table?

Tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE table.name.here MODIFY COLUMN insert_dt DATE;
```

I just get

`SQL compilation error: cannot change column INSERT_DT from type VARCHAR(16777216) to DATE`

Comment: Hi, looks like it is not supported, check this link by snowflake it tells what is supported and not supported. https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/alter-table-column.html

Comment: Wow. That is very surprising. Seems like a very rudimentary and basic thing to do...

Comment: Does column hold data which is of type "date" saved as string?

Comment: If the table is empty then drop the column and add again with the new data type, if you have data then use try_to_date function and convert it into the date data type and loaded into a new column with date data type.

Comment: Yes the values are i.e. '01/04/2022', but the column data type is string.

Comment: I'm trying to see if I can convert it to another data type then to date... this whole method of circumvention is a bit much, Snowflake, please make this possible in the future.

Comment: try_to_date  function on varchar column and get loaded into new column. Also oracle will also not support directly converting column from varchar to date directly.

Comment: It's not at all a rudimentary thing and isn't support in any RDBMS I've ever worked in. Create a temp table, move the data over, drop and recreate the table in question with the correct column types, and then move your data using `try_cast` or what-have-you to cast your string date into a proper date.

Answer (score 7):

I will just add some code to @David Garrison answer, to make it easier for lazy developers ;)

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> ADD COLUMN <COLUMN_NAME_TEMP> DATE;
UPDATE <TABLE_NAME> SET <COLUMN_NAME_TEMP> = TO_DATE(<COLUMN_NAME>);
ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> DROP COLUMN <COLUMN_NAME>;
ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> RENAME COLUMN <COLUMN_NAME_TEMP> to <COLUMN_NAME>;
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this sort of data type change is not allowed, generally your best option is to

1. Add a new column with a temp name, with the new data type
2. Run an update statement to set the new column to the old column's value (with any required transformations)
3. Rename the columns, and drop the old column if desired.

It is also sometimes easiest to do this change in a clone or CTAS table and then do an ALTER TABLE SWAP WITH.

Note that a full table update like this does mean recreating micro-partitions, which is generally ok (if a little slow), but you may want to keep an eye on if this affects your clustering. This is easier to control in a CTAS approach because you can explicitly maintain the ordering in an ORDER BY clause.